# Comparing data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi guys well I'm getting a null and i dont know why.. i'll apreciate if u can help me.

this is my json on Firebase.

```
usuarios{
 krum{
      dni: "43193622"
      email: "pedroccc"
      login: "krum"
      nombre:"pedro"
      pass: "1234" }
```

and this is my method:

```
login_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLogin);
```

onClickListener:

```
final String log_child = login_text.getText().toString();
final String pass_child = pass_text.getText().toString();
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("usuarios").child(log_child);

mDatabase.child("pass").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String mpass = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            pass = mpass;
            }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
     });
```

then i compare pass with pass_child with equals and i getting that pass is null.. any idea? thank you

PD. In Firebase all settings are true

Comment: where are you comparing?

Comment: then of this i use... if(pass.equals(pass_child))....

Comment: if i remove child("pass") the dataSnapshot will be a class right?

Comment: did the answer work?

Comment: no rlly.. I still getting the same error... the result is null.. so I initialized the "pass" to "" and I got the real pass when i press the button the 2nd time..

Comment: check the edit in the answer

Comment: Please provide the [**minimal**, **complete** code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now there are two things missing in the code you shared: 1) We have no way to know the value of `log_child`. Try to reproduce the problem with a hard-coded string, then update the code in your question with that. 2) You didn't share how/where you do the comparison. Add that to the minimal snippet that reproduces the problem, and we'll have a better chance of seeing what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
final String log_child = login_text.getText().toString();
final String pass_child = pass_text.getText().toString();
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("usuarios").child(log_child);

mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        String mpass = data.getValue().toString();
        pass = mpass;
        if(pass.equals(pass_child)){
            //code here
         }
        }
   }

 @Override
 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
 });
```

Adding the for loop will enable you to get the pass from the database. Since `onDatachange` is asynchronous(means it does not wait until it finishes retrieving data, and it goes to other methods after it, then when it retrieves the data it comes back to the method `onDatachange`) then you have to compare inside the method `onDatachange`